# NSURLCredential cant compile in Swift

Tags: swift

I have some compilation problems with latest XCode 6.1 (6A1046a)

This line will compile:

```
var newCredential = NSURLCredential(user: "test", password: "test", persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.None);
```

But this one throws error "Extra argument 'identity' in call":

```
var identita : SecIdentity = self.getClientCertificate();
var newCredential2 = NSURLCredential(identity: identita, certificates: nil, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.None);
```

But I don't know why. According to manual it should work: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLCredential/credentialWithIdentity:certificates:persistence:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error Swift is giving you is misleading (a common issue if one of the arguments you're passing to a function is the wrong type). The problem is that `certificates` is defined as `[AnyObject]`, but you're passing it `nil`. Since `certificates` isn't an optional, it can't take a `nil` value. The documentation also says:

> An array of **one or more** SecCertificateRef objects representing
>   certificates for the credential.

So, you should be passing it an array of at least one certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler diagnostics are bad here. What's actually happening is you passed in `nil` for the `certificates` argument but that argument takes a non-optional `[AnyObject]`, and the compiler couldn't find an initializer that matched that type. Try passing in `[]` (the empty array) instead.